# Office/Outlook Add In: Attach debugger not available?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I recently came back to an Outlook add-in project, and I updated all of my Office apps.  Outlook is currently Version 1906 (Build 11727.20244 Click-to-Run) on Windows 10 Pro (not running any insider’s version). However, after I open the add-in, no context menu opens when I right-click.  I’m trying to debug the add-in running in native Outlook on Windows because something is broken (the same code works fine in OWA and Outlook for Mac).

I’m a bit stuck if I can’t attach a debugger.  Nothing shows up in F12 developer tools either.  However if I open the Insights add-in, I can right click and attach a debugger as you would expect.

Why would I not be able to even see the right-click context menu in my add-in?

Comment: When you say F12 developer tools, are you referring to this tool : C:\Windows\System32\F12\IEChooser.exe? When you launch this tool, do you see a list of debuggable HTML pages that excludes that of your add-in?

Comment: Also, do the instructions here help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

Comment: I think I was having a cache issue with Outlook. Once I uninstalled/reinstalled Outlook, it worked fine. The addin was working in OWA the whole time, so I knew it was related to the desktop Outlook app.

Answer (score 0):

> However, after I open the add-in, no context menu opens when I right-click.

Try to create a new empty add-in in Visual Studio. If you get the context menu shown there, you just need to compare both projects and find the difference between them.